# Using lapply to create a conditional sum of column values over a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I have data that looks like the sample below:

```
[[1]]
           KRW.LOW.1 KRW.LOW.1.1 KRW.50D   KRW.LOW.1.2
2014-08-11        -1          1       1    5
2014-08-12        -1          1       1    10

[[2]]]
           EUR.CLOSE EUR.CLOSE.1 EUR.50D   EUR.CLOSE.2
2014-08-29        -1          -1       1    3
2014-09-01        -1           1       1    1
2014-09-02         0          -1       0    2
```

This is a list of dataframes. And I want to sum the elements in the 4th row (VAR.CLOSE.2) based on a condition for the first three columns. The conditions are:

1. Column 1 has nonnegative values OR
2. Column 2 is strictly greater than zero OR
3. Column 3 is nonnegative

In other words, as an illustrative example, if I was just examining a single dataframe, I'd want something like `sum(x[which(x[,1]!=0 | x[,2]>0 | x[,3]!=0]), 4)`

So in the given example above, I'd like to get the following calculations:

```
[[1]]
              KRW 
ReturnSum     15 


[[2]]
              EUR 
ReturnSum     5
```

Where we get 5 for EUR from summing the only first 2 rows because the last row doesn't fulfill any of the 3 conditions. In particular, the conditions`Data[[2]][3,1] != 0` `Data[[2]][3,3] != 0` both fail and so does `Data[[2]][3,2]>0`

I've tried achieving this with

```
i <- 1:length(FlaggingTrend)
SumReturns <- lapply(FlaggingTrend[[i]], function(x) sum(x[which(x[,2]!=0|x[,3]>0|x[,4]!=0),4]))
```

Where FlaggingTrend corresponds to the data posted above. However, this returns a list of zeroes.

I'll be attaching a sample dput of the data below:

```
list(structure(list(EUR.CLOSE = c(-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 
0, 1), EUR.CLOSE.1 = c(1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1), EUR.50D = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), EUR.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.0011268664916733, 
-0.00423709498833686, -0.00188893142678216, 0.00217196364717242, 
0.00686254162079234, -0.00544858088184653, -0.000188412624203348, 
-0.00737591996472312, 0.00208590196044455, 0.00227057808051545
)), .Names = c("EUR.CLOSE", "EUR.CLOSE.1", "EUR.50D", "EUR.CLOSE.2"
), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", 
"2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", 
"2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(JPY.CLOSE = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1), JPY.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), JPY.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), JPY.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.000264935754629825, 0.00458231327013969, 
0.00456141141766331, -0.000875580127735809, -0.00809151292488242, 
-0.00353857410990255, 0.00230149698827908, 0.00511510066677001, 
-0.00326005839636956, -0.00619690368354142)), .Names = c("JPY.CLOSE", 
"JPY.CLOSE.1", "JPY.50D", "JPY.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
"2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
"2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GBP.CLOSE = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1), GBP.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GBP.50D = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), GBP.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00048023051987453, 
    0.00279809911944895, -0.00464112219813048, -0.000561594944360089, 
    0.0022444899202175, -0.00618451029481418, 0.00410050825810596, 
    0.000802053299332334, -0.00184568523285542, 0.00847801606899046
    )), .Names = c("GBP.CLOSE", "GBP.CLOSE.1", "GBP.50D", "GBP.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        CHF.OPEN = c(1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1), CHF.OPEN.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1), CHF50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CHF.OPEN.2 = c(0.000698567964139939, 
        0.00328669186857626, 0.00049704260678339, -0.000695928844511353, 
        -0.00838914337795957, 0.00550083899465574, 0.000199461454735274, 
        0.00685716972613716, 0.000594059423411153, -0.00396707849439904
        )), .Names = c("CHF.OPEN", "CHF.OPEN.1", "CHF50D", "CHF.OPEN.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        AUD.CLOSE = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0), AUD.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AUD.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), AUD.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00640566933128534, 
        -0.00444038864633145, 0.00300594880983807, 0.0061146355869709, 
        -0.00207738324513479, -0.00390676366154397, 0.00312663099943206, 
        -0.00169237819473061, 0.00364156989756792, 0.00155662244429539
        )), .Names = c("AUD.CLOSE", "AUD.CLOSE.1", "AUD.50D", 
    "AUD.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CAD.CLOSE = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1), CAD.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), CAD.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CAD.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00472778065310547, 
    -0.000917641725324381, 0.000382453058549392, 0.000305857167088586, 
    -0.000688310225637978, 0.00191080426541917, 0.000763300548471235, 
    0.00266697304419594, 0.00174871741959248, -0.00449199430572389
    )), .Names = c("CAD.CLOSE", "CAD.CLOSE.1", "CAD.50D", "CAD.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        NZD.CLOSE = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1), NZD.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NZD.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), NZD.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00041733324664972, 
        -0.00208841008727045, -0.000836586774949688, 0.00750420419797471, 
        -0.00180142777185216, -0.00389105549296664, 0.00111327592906424, 
        -0.00404153570815258, 0.00390244397693174, 0.00568695616893883
        )), .Names = c("NZD.CLOSE", "NZD.CLOSE.1", "NZD.50D", 
    "NZD.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(SEK.OPEN = c(1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    ), SEK.OPEN.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1), 
        SEK.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SEK.OPEN.2 = c(0.00163829609003363, 
        0.0023181988913219, -0.000716164076936199, -0.00145628918509555, 
        -0.00677152707834994, 0.00582941106111079, 0.00270059947077783, 
        0.00455540960162004, -0.000256248852460228, 0.00199255363165785
        )), .Names = c("SEK.OPEN", "SEK.OPEN.1", "SEK.50D", "SEK.OPEN.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        NOK.CLOSE = c(1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), NOK.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), NOK.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NOK.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00323283885094217, 
        0.00303175214315887, 0.000941075635438882, -0.00716968871997281, 
        -0.00617111408142934, 0.00665069589528811, -0.000467589464977269, 
        0.00246736261239189, 0.000837040274633605, -0.00324444329976892
        )), .Names = c("NOK.CLOSE", "NOK.CLOSE.1", "NOK.50D", 
    "NOK.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CZK.CLOSE = c(1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1), CZK.CLOSE.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CZK.50D = c(1, 
    1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1), CZK.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00144601789180365, 
    0.00379617459269976, 0.00202579528819546, -0.00220231606416821, 
    -0.00688897736863447, 0.00560532297819627, 0.000184602212216056, 
    0.00710284457208665, -0.00197121312914339, -0.00224919172846905
    )), .Names = c("CZK.CLOSE", "CZK.CLOSE.1", "CZK.50D", "CZK.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        HUF.LOW.1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), HUF.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1), HUF.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), HUF.LOW.1.2 = c(0.0013470806658562, 
        0.00413351833762921, 0.000927691660614904, -0.00161542594720476, 
        -0.00908798735735505, 0.00843420139734707, -0.00110208028787984, 
        0.00632043873779775, -0.00133632598823841, 0.000719782039952932
        )), .Names = c("HUF.LOW.1", "HUF.LOW.1.1", "HUF.50D", 
    "HUF.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ILS.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ILS.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), ILS.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ILS.LOW.1.2 = c(0.000933818987030266, 
    0.000959590648321962, -0.00159982969276018, -0.00296644925366696, 
    -0.00509821862018822, -0.00393531505179312, 0.00242770943578163, 
    -0.00285991992901691, -0.000567559913074556, 0.00091874516690349
    )), .Names = c("ILS.LOW.1", "ILS.LOW.1.1", "ILS.50D", "ILS.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        PLN.LOW.1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLN.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), PLN.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PLN.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00274633685326608, 
        0.00755279414139087, 0.000417931735706034, -0.000491702529882065, 
        -0.00490565626173578, 0.00929781633628868, -0.00365469691428677, 
        0.00186580959045224, -0.00137446945036213, -0.00149934278232444
        )), .Names = c("PLN.LOW.1", "PLN.LOW.1.1", "PLN.50D", 
    "PLN.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(RUB.LOW.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1, 1), RUB.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), RUB.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RUB.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00446008580014645, 
    -0.0121748200414373, -0.00422818336649922, -0.0153488129381678, 
    0.0022241309795028, 0.00590173583792808, 0.014758577509606, 
    -0.00824954514944221, -0.00941636498473652, 0.0111898627811513
    )), .Names = c("RUB.LOW.1", "RUB.LOW.1.1", "RUB.50D", "RUB.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        TRY.HIGH.1 = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1), TRY.HIGH.1.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), TRY.50D = c(-1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), TRY.HIGH.1.2 = c(0.00417356089701015, 
        -0.00686579177053992, -0.00568012668941198, 0.00229778255761226, 
        0.00204713949728741, -0.0100024127023963, -0.00176420367173535, 
        -0.00113183078791668, -0.011249649909296, -0.00307744199905646
        )), .Names = c("TRY.HIGH.1", "TRY.HIGH.1.1", "TRY.50D", 
    "TRY.HIGH.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ZAR.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
    -1), ZAR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), ZAR.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ZAR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.0050112296343281, 
    -0.000119978703923884, -0.0173679300039469, -0.0145343910929765, 
    0.00897924634581271, 0.000421926368602055, 0.000521408427958114, 
    0.00716476609655059, -0.0126608692527035, -0.00785440574245699
    )), .Names = c("ZAR.LOW.1", "ZAR.LOW.1.1", "ZAR.50D", "ZAR.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        BRL.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1), BRL.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), BRL.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BRL.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00371652356533581, 
        -0.00160621962638552, -0.00832934597660584, -0.00902065874268554, 
        0.010543197464703, 0.00316721872930192, -0.00362049854021018, 
        0.00278119317749237, -0.0100617531753731, -0.0006199931673041
        )), .Names = c("BRL.LOW.1", "BRL.LOW.1.1", "BRL.50D", 
    "BRL.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CLP.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), CLP.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), CLP.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CLP.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00993671434599985, 
    0.00456853190734918, -0.00172828592427443, -0.00404432121904819, 
    -0.00048516719656444, 0.00933326604643625, -0.00561445365426927, 
    0.00353409520664982, -0.00208469536279665, -0.00105956972687871
    )), .Names = c("CLP.LOW.1", "CLP.LOW.1.1", "CLP.50D", "CLP.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        COP.CLOSE = c(-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1), COP.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), COP.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), COP.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00197341552292052, 
        0.00662211307234362, 0.000580874632634121, -0.00202234392720335, 
        0.00204668459925017, 0.00543743450560008, -0.00266994190200176, 
        0.00607751193077277, -0.00217715796204931, -0.00905605289811184
        )), .Names = c("COP.CLOSE", "COP.CLOSE.1", "COP.50D", 
    "COP.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(MXN.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), MXN.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), MXN.50D = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), MXN.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.000211320384603475, 
    -0.00314066280938086, -0.00107540683430729, 0.000705557901050646, 
    0.00518510570127306, 0.00240140867288519, -0.00281365838425973, 
    -0.0177295559643031, -0.00536567713104841, -0.0121193389083811
    )), .Names = c("MXN.LOW.1", "MXN.LOW.1.1", "MXN.50D", "MXN.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        PEN.HIGH.1 = c(-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0), PEN.HIGH.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), PEN.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PEN.HIGH.1.2 = c(-0.00429316820091041, 
        0.00214888801033619, -0.000859001157250239, -0.0038438522704316, 
        0.00101621330746293, 0.00460618041489735, -0.00522194398115183, 
        0, -0.000462071629322658, -0.000154071335332739)), .Names = c("PEN.HIGH.1", 
    "PEN.HIGH.1.1", "PEN.50D", "PEN.HIGH.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CNY.CLOSE = c(1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    -1), CNY.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), CNY.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CNY.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00135295379134326, 
    0.000247116371263401, -0.00184758230288495, 0.000524070878021865, 
    -0.0026376972616271, 0.001968002384513, 0.00174608993071379, 
    0.000799273430379666, -0.00090104498241117, -0.00170257391661588
    )), .Names = c("CNY.CLOSE", "CNY.CLOSE.1", "CNY.50D", "CNY.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        IDR.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), IDR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1), IDR.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), IDR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00225360672301989, 
        0.00142787383820853, 0.000750694427567922, 0.000375135991193432, 
        -0.000825485019296579, 0.000975500021079156, 0.00157380030235466, 
        0.00142178345498323, -0.000448765901323256, -0.00119769458137853
        )), .Names = c("IDR.LOW.1", "IDR.LOW.1.1", "IDR.50D", 
    "IDR.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(INR.LOW.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    ), INR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), INR.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1), INR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.000466530150061928, 
    -0.000531550320954643, -0.000443420116883253, -0.000392023361358795, 
    -0.000386278564721287, -0.000386427833512393, -0.000244913256195467, 
    -0.000181510566847898, -0.000126929400856568, -0.000132850348706803
    )), .Names = c("INR.LOW.1", "INR.LOW.1.1", "INR.50D", "INR.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-08", "2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-22"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        KRW.LOW.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
        KRW.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1
        ), KRW.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KRW.LOW.1.2 = c(0.000517860571988438, 
        0.000112542907102053, 0.00134952787013343, 0, -0.000337211266051574, 
        0.00112359562382647, 0.000449084996881899, 0.000785413785115541, 
        -0.00085276367906495, -0.000718681250895026)), .Names = c("KRW.LOW.1", 
    "KRW.LOW.1.1", "KRW.50D", "KRW.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell want you want. maybe something like: `lapply(dat,function(x) sum(x[which(x[1:3,1]!=0 | x[1:3,2]>0 | x[1:3,3]!=0),4]))`

Comment: @count Sorry, yeah. I might try editing my examples with simpler data so that it isn't so much of an eyesore. I'm not sure if `x[which(x[1:3,1]!=0 | x[1:3,2]>0 | x[1:3,3]!=0),4]` will work because I'm working with a much larger dataset spanning about 200+ rows. I'll edit my post to be more clear.

Comment: @count Also sorry, I tried using your `lapply` function but I got a list of `NA`

Answer (score 0):

You could try working with purrr:

```
map_df(FlaggingTrend, function(x) {
co <- stringr::str_extract(names(x)[1], "\\w+")
names(x) <- c(names(x[[1]]))
x %>% 
    filter(EUR.CLOSE != 0, EUR.50D > 0, EUR.CLOSE.1 != 0) %>% 
    mutate(co = co) %>%
    group_by(co) %>%
    summarize(Sum_Var = sum(EUR.CLOSE.2))
})
```

Every data frame in the list has it's columns renamed to the first one. This does not return the values in your example, but the filtering should work just fine.

Comment: I'm not faimiliar with purr, but thanks for this! However, when I tried it I got an error saying foo not found. When I replaced foo with FlaggingTrend, I ended up getting  Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = "CZK") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Comment: Just an error on my part. Map_df works much like lapply so you define each element in the list as a function of x. I just didn't fix a variable from my tinkering.

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you again but after changing to x I'm getting `Error: Each variable must be named. Problem variables: 1, 2, 3, 4`.  I'm sorry if this is a rather silly question, but could this be because of `filter(EUR.CLOSE!= 0 ...)` since I have more variables (that are similarly structured) named JPY, GBP, CHF, NOK...etc?

Comment: No problem. I was able to reproduce the problem and find a fix. It has to do with the way I setup renaming each individual element x. `names(x[[1]])` changes with each element of the list. That's what we DO NOT want to happen. To see why just run `map_df(FlaggingTrend, function(x) x)`. This binds the columns together but does not create a useful data frame.

So, we need to create a static list of names that each column can use. I just used: `name_list <- names(FlaggingTrend[[1]])` and assigned that to `names(x)`. The rest should work after that.